# how to use splice in angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5, splice, array-splice

I have created a table that displays data fetched from the database. The TS part that fetches the data looks something like:

```js
this._appService.getVisitData().subscribe((data) => {
  this.checkinTemp = data;
  // Calling the DT trigger to manually render the table
  this.dtTrigger.next();
});
```

The table gets generated and I have added an edit and delete function, my view code:

```html
<table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" class="row-border hover">

  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Visitor Name</th>
    <th>Department</th>
    <th>Purpose</th>
    <th>Schedule Date Time</th>
    <th>Entry Source</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let data of checkinTemp">
    <td>{{data.id}}</td>
    <td>
      <a  (click)="viewCheckinData(data)"> {{data.f_name}} {{data.l_name}} </a>
      <span>
            <a  (click)="editCheckinData(data)">Edit</a>
        <a  (click)="confirmDelete(data)">Delete</a>
      </span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span *ngIf="data.department == null || data.department == ''">N/A</span>
      <span *ngIf="data.department !== null ">{{data.department}}</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span *ngIf="data.purpose == null || data.purpose == ''">N/A</span>
      <span *ngIf="data.purpose !== null ">{{data.purpose}}</span>
    </td>
    <td>{{data.pre_check_in | date:'short'}}</td>
    <td>{{data.creator_id}}</td>
  </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>


<p-confirmDialog header="Confirmation" icon="fa fa-question-circle" width="425"></p-confirmDialog>
```

Now when the user presses delete the `confirmDelete(data)` gets called. The function in the TS file:

```js
confirmDelete(item) {
  this.confirmationService.confirm({
    message: 'Are you sure you want to delete this Visitor?',
    header: 'Confirmation',
    accept: () => {
      this._appService.deleteCheckin(item.id).subscribe(res => {
        // Splice Or something so the page doesnt reload but the data gets removed from the view.
        this.flashMsg.flashMsg('success', 'Deleted', 'Visitor has been deleted.');
      },
      err => {
        this.flashMsg.flashMsg('error', 'Error', 'Visitor has not been deleted.');
      });
    },
    reject: () => {
    },
  });
}
```

Until now when I delete data, the data gets deleted and the confirmation message pops up, but the data is still displayed in the view until the page gets reloaded. Is there a way to remove the data from the table without the page loading? I looked up splice but had no luck using it in the code.

Comment: Splice doesn’t mutate arrays, it creates a new one. Use like myArray = myArray.splice(0,1) to see results

Comment: @bryan60 it most definitely DOES mutate arrays, and returns the removed items. Did you get `slice(...)` and `splice(...)` mixed up?... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After you have successfully deleted your item from the server, you can delete it from the array using `splice(...)` like this:

```js
const index = this.checkinTemp.indexOf(item);
this.checkinTemp.splice(index, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
this.checkinTemp = [...this.checkinTemp.filter(i => {i !== item})];
```

we can filter the array and make a deep copy of the array to store the updated data